# Font color of disabled buttons

Tags: wpf

How do I find the exact gray color of a font when the IsEnabled property of a button is false?  It appears that there are subtle differences between versions of windows, so I want to get this color from the system to ensure IsEnable colors match.

Comment: I think this question would be better asked on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). However, don't repost I can migrate the question for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the control template here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx

You can see that the foreground colour when the button is disabled is defined as follows:

```
<Color x:Key="DisabledForegroundColor">#FF888888</Color>
```

You should be able to look up DisabledForegroundColor (this.Resources["DisabledForegroundColor"]) from your code.